# How can I do feature based deployment in a correct way in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

This is my azure-pipeline.yml file and trying to create feature based deployment by using below code blog but I want to read this part from another yaml file. This is possible ?

```js
parameters:
  - name: skipDevTestUAT
    type: boolean
    default: false
trigger:
  branches:
    include: 
      - origin/feature/Yusuf/branch1
      - origin/feature/Yusuf/branch2
```

please check my below azure-pipeline.yml code

1. This is a Feature Based Deployment?
2. I will share here our pipeline deployment. I hope this is correct way

```
# Feature Based Deployment
# I will share here our pipeline deployment via feature based Deployment

parameters:
  - name: skipDevTestUAT
    type: boolean
    default: false
trigger:
  branches:
    include: 
      - origin/feature/Yusuf/branch1
      - origin/feature/Yusuf/branch2


# Rest of your pipeline configuration

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: DEV
    displayName: "DEV Stage"
    jobs:
      - job: DEV_Job
        displayName: "DEV Job"
        steps:
          - script: echo "Perform DEV deployment"

  - stage: TEST
    displayName: "TEST Stage"
    dependsOn: DEV
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.skipDevTestUAT }}', 'false'))
    jobs:
      - job: TEST_Job
        displayName: 'TEST Job'
        steps:
          - script: echo "Perform TEST deployment"

  - stage: UAT
    displayName: "UAT Stage"
    dependsOn: TEST
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.skipDevTestUAT }}', 'false'))
    jobs:
      - job: UAT_Job
        displayName: 'UAT Job'
        steps:
          - script: echo "Perform UAT deployment"

  - stage: PROD
    displayName: "PROD Stage"
    dependsOn: UAT
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.skipDevTestUAT }}', 'true'))
    jobs:
      - job: PROD_Job
        displayName: 'PROD Job'
        steps:
          - script: echo "Perform PROD deployment"
```

Can I put this part into project-template.yml?

```js
parameters:
  - name: skipDevTestUAT
    type: boolean
    default: false
trigger:
  branches:
    include: 
      - origin/feature/Yusuf/branch1
      - origin/feature/Yusuf/branch2
```

If you have any idea , I am totally open for it? btw Can we say it is a feature based deployment ?

Comment: If I follow the quick answer is the trigger can't be parameters; however, the parameter you have could be moved to a variable template.yml file which will have different values in each branch. Then the appropriate variables based on repo would be loaded into the pipeline. If it sounds right I can provide an example as an answer

Comment: Hi @DreadedFrost Thank you for your answer, It sounds right!  Please provide me with a sample...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the variable file would be loaded and [scoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#variable-scopes) appropriately. Based on your provided code it would most likely be root level since it is being used to evaluate conditions across stages. I would recommend, if keeping it as is, removing the condition and reading it as [conditional insertion to the stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion). The difference here is the stage won't even load into the Pipeline if the criteria isn't met vs always being present and skipped.

Also for finer grain control another option would be a variable file per environment. The template file will have a different name, most likely containing some part of the environment name in it. Then load the variable file at the stage or job as appropriate. This could give more control to run certain jobs/tasks in DEV and not UAT.

For your specific ask it would look something like:

```
variables:
- template: variables.yml
trigger:
  branches:
    include: 
      - origin/feature/Yusuf/branch1
      - origin/feature/Yusuf/branch2

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
stages:
- stage: TEST
  displayName: "TEST Stage"
  dependsOn: DEV
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ variables.skipDevTestUAT }}', 'false'))
  jobs:
     - job: TEST_Job
       displayName: 'TEST Job'
       steps:
        - script: echo "Perform TEST deployment"
```

variables.yml:

```
variables:
  - name: skipDevTestUAT 
    value: false
```

To skip even reading the stage it would be:

```
stages:
-${{ if eq('${{ variables.skipDevTestUAT }}', 'false') }} :
  - stage: TEST
    displayName: "TEST Stage"
    dependsOn: DEV
    jobs:
    - job: TEST_Job
      displayName: 'TEST Job'
      steps:
        - script: echo "Perform TEST deployment"
```

As an FYI as it always seems to come up...to evaluate that your variables are being inserted correctly after the pipeline executes select the elipse menue, download log, and view the azure-pipeline-expane

Here's some follow up material on how to do some of this at scale. [Microsoft Series on YAML Pipelines](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/bg-p/HealthcareAndLifeSciencesBlog/label-name/YAML%20Pipeline%20Series) and an [example on using if/else](https://blog.johnfolberth.com/one-yaml-pipeline-for-ci-cd/) to load stages based on criteria.